# Who is Saber extending her hand to in the ED of Carnival Phantasm?

Tags: fate-stay-night, tsukihime, carnival-phantasm

In the ED, we see each character (that appears in the show) is connected by (the proximity of) a hand.

Right as the ED of Carnival Phantasm ends, we see Saber [extending her hand to someone](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ofR4M.jpg), but we never see who that person is.

Was the identity of this hand ever revealed? If so, who is it?

[image: Who's that hand?!]

Answer (score 6):

That arm could be the arm of Kiritsugu Emiya. In the picture the characters are connected to thier masters. The masters of Saber would be Shirou Emiya and Kiritsugu Emiya.

It could also be the arm of Irisviel van Einzbern, who wasn't the real master of Saber but some sort of stand-in, while Kiritsugu was doing his dirty work.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fate/Zero#Characters

Comment: I'm not really convinced by this. Carnival Phantasm doesn't have any Fate/Zero characters, and Kiritsugu exists in Fate/Stay Night only in a small number of flashbacks (and Irisviel not at all). Do you have any sources to back up this claim?

Answer (score 6):

There's a [zerochan image](http://www.zerochan.net/873377) suggesting that it's Irisviel:

[image]

However, it credits a Pixiv user so chances are that it ain't official. Nevertheless, there are some bases for such an assumption:

- Irisviel has a connection to Saber (being the stand-in Master during Fate/Zero)
- the arm looks feminine
- Despite [Logan M's comment](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/3002/who-is-saber-extending-her-hand-to-in-the-ed-of-carnival-phantasm#comment2381_3105) Fate/Zero characters do appear in the Ahnenerbe party [after the credits](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7xk24zV5_KA&t=15m33s), even Iris.

[image: Omigawd it's Irisviel]

[image: Real Emiya family]

So it stands to reason that Irisviel is the most likely candidate.

Answer (score 2):

This is an interesting question.

If you pay attention to the forearm of the hidden character, it is not covered in sleeves, nor is it decorated with anything, like a wrist band, so Kiritsugu is out. Saber's friendly gesture towards the unknown person shows a moderately close affinity between them, so again it can't be Kiritsugu because Saber dislikes him and would have shown an anxious face like Bazett's if it's his hand that is reaching out to her.

While Irisviel von Einzbern fits all these bills and is indeed a likely candidate, the size of the hand seems to be slightly larger than that of Saber and about equal to that of Shirou, which suggests the hand of a delicate man over that of a delicate woman.

I think Saber is extending her hand to her male archetype counterpart: [Prototype Saber](https://typemoon.fandom.com/wiki/Arthur_Pendragon#Casual) from *[Fate/Prototype](https://typemoon.fandom.com/wiki/Fate/Prototype)*, which was released as a movie special bundled with the 3rd Season of *Carnival Phantasm*.

[image: Prototype Saber in casual wear]

The [official website](https://www.typemoon.com/products/cp/outline.html#cp3rd) doesn't even hint at the content of this "special movie"; instead, we have Ayaka Sajou calling the Ahnenerbe at the end of disc 1 after the ED sequence plays for one last time as lead-ins to *Fate/Prototype*, which is disc 2. The incompleteness of the character sequence can be seen as an acknowledgement to the fact that *Fate/Prototype* never came to fruition.

On the other hand, *Fate/Grand Carnival*, *Carnival Phantasm*'s spiritual sequel, also did something similar in their [EDs](https://www.reddit.com/r/grandorder/comments/q7zjav/fategrand_carnival_ending_both_versions/) where the character sequence stops halfway at the hind legs of [Red Hare](https://typemoon.fandom.com/wiki/Red_Hare), but is continued and ends unambiguously on [Castoria](https://typemoon.fandom.com/wiki/Artoria_Caster), signifying that *Fate/Grand Order* is a largely complete series with its own anime adaptations.

Now back to the claim that Saber is reaching her hand out to Irisviel. As Memor-X has pointed out in her [answer](https://anime.stackexchange.com/a/15459/8486), characters from *Fate/Zero*, as well as novels by Kinoko Nasu that have yet to be adapted into video game format, do appear in the Ahnenerbe party after the ending credits of the last episode. It's worth noting that the *Fate/Zero* anime began airing in between the releases of the 1st and 2nd Seasons of *Carnival Phantasm*, so I'd imagine Lerche would have issues drawing *Fate/Zero* characters before Ufotable did them. But then, why do a veiled advertisement for an upcoming anime by one of their rivals when Lerche had one planned for themselves in the form of a movie special? Moreover, TYPE-MOON is foremost a video game company; the mere fact that one of Nasu's novels received an anime adaptation does not bestow a place in the ED sequence upon its characters. Cases in point: *Kara no Kyoukai*, *Canaan* and, yes, *Fate/Zero*.

There is also the viewpoint that the hand belongs to [Aoko Aozaki](https://typemoon.fandom.com/wiki/Aoko_Aozaki#Original), the heroine of *Witch on the Holy Night* and a playable character in *Melty Blood Actress Again*. This comes from the observation that the characters in the ED sequence appear in chronological order of TYPE-MOON's franchises: the *Tsukihime* series, the *Melty Blood* series and the *Fate* series. The next in line would be *Witch on the Holy Night*, which was first set to be released in 2009, but due to [numerous delays](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Witch_on_the_Holy_Night#Development_and_release), was finally only able to push out a demo by mid-December, 2011, and the full game by mid-April, 2012. This setback was probably the reason why the [TYPE-MOON Fes. 10th Anniversary Event](https://typemoon.fandom.com/wiki/TYPE-MOON_Fes.) was postponed to July, 2012, when all of *Carnival Phantasm*, save for the [HibiChika Special](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carnival_Phantasm#List_of_episodes), had already been released half a year ago and were themselves already a late celebration for TYPE-MOON's 10th anniversary, sometime in 2009 or 2010 depending on how you count it. Thereby, Lerche would have to use the *Melty Blood* outfit for Aoko, hence the bare forearm.

However, how are Aoko and Saber related to warrant them being so close to each other and not divided into "camps"? This proposal falls short in favor of Prototype Saber, which I hereby conclude is the identity of the mostly hidden character at the end of the ED sequence. It may have been Aoko in the original planning, maybe *Fate/Prototype* was even animated precisely to fill in for the yet undelivered *Witch on the Holy Night*. Whatever the case, all evidence presented so far point to none other than Prototype Saber in the final rendition of the ED sequence. Q.E.D.